# Can't expose Constants from Singleton or Property

Tags: c#

```
public class MySingletonClass
{
    private static MySingletonClass mySingletonClass;
    private const decimal someDiscount = 3.00M;

    public static MySingletonClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (mySingletonClass == null)
                mySingletonClass = new mySingletonClass();

            return mySingletonClass;
        }
    }
    ....

   public static decimal SomeDiscount
 {
  get { return this.someDiscount;}
    }
    ...
  }
```

I'm trying to expose the someDiscount as a property so I can use it with the static Instance property later on.  I guess you can't do this with a constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `this.` before `someDiscount`. Constants are inherently static and cannot be accessed using an instance qualifier.

That said, this is a somewhat unusual pattern. Either the field *is* constant and will never change, in which case you'd tend to expose it as such...

```
public const decimal SomeDiscount = 3M;
```

...or it *isn't* a constant and so you wouldn't tend to want an explicitly named constant for it, but just return it from the property...

```
public static decimal SomeDiscount
{
    get { return 3M; }
}
```

...having both seems somewhat contradictory.

Answer (score 4):

Use of **this** seems off in a static method. What happens when you remove it?

Answer (score 3):

remove **this** keyword a constant is automatically a static

```
 public static decimal SomeDiscount
        {
            get { return someDiscount; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you just can't use the this qualifier, as it is redundant. valid would be return someDiscount or return MySingletonClass.someDiscount.

think of const just like static.

Answer (score 0):

Somediscount should not be static(sorry for the short response I'm trying to answer this from my iPhone)